# angular2 route parameter with additional url

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

Is it possible to have this kind of link?

`/machine/:id/parameter`
`/machine/DD1AB59B-C7FE-4050-98BE-FDEE07E36D83/parameters`

So i could do something like:
`<a routerLink="/machine/{{machine.id}}/parameters">Parameters</a>`

is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. What's the problem here?

Comment: Endeed, this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did here:

```
{
    path: 'machine/:id',
    component: MachineComponent
},
{
    path: 'machines/machine/:id/parameters',
    component: MachineParametersComponent
}
```

I couldnt add the `parameters` route as child, cause then it excpects another route-outlet, which in my case didnt work.